# Find all partitions of $Z_{60}$ ($3$ classes with $20$ elements), such that any two elements $a,b$ from the class satisfy $gcd(a-b,60)\not\in\{2,5\}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that the residue classes modulo $3$ is the only partition of the set $Z_{60}=\{0,1,\ldots,59\}$ such that the family of eqaul sized classes is of the size three and any two elements in the class satisfy $\gcd(a-b,60)\not\in \{2,5\}$.

According to computer search the statement is true.
Moreover, it can be seen that, if $C_1$ is one such class in some partition of $Z_{60}$ then the sets $C_1+2$, $C_1+5$, $C_1+14$,... are potential classes in the same partition. However, the disjunctiveness of the such union should be shown.